# TideSDK crashes when loading java applet

Tags: tidesdk

When loading an iframe containing a java applet everything crashes, including the debug window so there's no data on the crash.

This was done by loading up a Tide project with only an iframe element inside it pointing at a ny website, then clicking through the website to reach their java applet. As soon as the applet is intended to load it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

can you file an issue on our github: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/

Also please mention the exact version of TideSDK you are using and also mention the platform you are in.

This seems to be issue with the webkit which is due getting upgraded in next major version 1.4.0. We will investigate the same.